# Is the set {a,b} uniquely defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

First answer to this question would be *yes*, but consider the following question: How many elements has the set $\{a,\, b\}$? The answer to this question depends on $a$ and $b$:

- If $a=b$, then $\{a,\, b\}$ is a singleton.
- If $a\neq b$, then $\{a,\, b\}$ has two elements.

So is $\{a,\, b\}$ uniquely defined although its cardinality is not unique? I have two possible answers solving this problem:

**Solution 1:** Because of the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) a set is uniquely defined, iff one can say for each object whether it is element of the set or not. So $\{a,\, b\}$ is uniquely defined because one can say that an object $x$ is element of $\{a,\, b\}$, iff $x=a$ or $x=b$. The uniqueness of a set does not imply the uniqueness of its cardinality.

**Solution 2:** If $a$ and $b$ are in the context defined objects (which do not depend on free variables), then $\{a,\, b\}$ as well as its cardinality is uniquely defined. If $a$ and $b$ are free variables or depend on free variables, then asking for the cardinality of $\{a,\, b\}$ is the same as asking for the truth of a statement form $A(x)$ with a free variable $x$: It doesn't make sense. Just after substituting all free variables with uniquely defined objects, on can ask for the cardinality of $\{a,\, b\}$.

Which of my solutions is right or is there a better solution? What is the right answer to someone who says that the set $\{a,b\}$ is not unique?

Comment: Are you asking if $$\forall x\forall y\exists !z\left((x\in z\land y\in z)\to \forall w(w\in z\to (w=x\lor w=y) )\right)?$$

Comment: @GitGud: I want to know: What is the right answer to someone saying that $\{a,b\}$ is not uniquely defined because its cardinality is not unique? In a course where the professor introduces to elementary set theory, this might be a possible question of a student.

Comment: The cardinality of $\{ a,b \}$ **is** uniquely defined; if $a=b$, then it is $1$; if $a \ne b$ then it is $2$.

Comment: it depends on context. in certain situations writing a set as $\left\{a,b\right\}$ means that $a$ and $b$ are distinct; otherwise you wouldn't have written $b$. (in other words, sometimes it is conventional for different letters to denote different elements.) but in other contexts, you may want to treat the letters as variables, in which case it could turn out that $a=b$.

Comment: @tampis You can consider the logical truth $a=b\lor \neg a=b$. To claim the cardinality of $\{a,b\}$ isn't uniquely defined, you need to prove in one of the cases of the logical truth that you get two different cardinalities. Getting different cardinalities in different cases doesn't mean anything.

Comment: The only thing your question turns on is, given a set $x$ that contains exactly $a,b$ and given a set $y$ containing exactly $a,b$, whether $x$ and $y$ can ever be different sets. That's all.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Let be $x$ a real number with $x^2=1$. So is also $x$ uniquely defined because I can say: "If $x<0$, then $x=-1$ and if $x\ge 0$, then $x=1$"?!

Comment: but the set $\{ x_1, x_2 \}$ of *roots* of $x^2=1$ **is** uniquely defined and has two elements, also if I have not "decided" which of them is $< 0$ and which is $\ge 0$.

Comment: @GitGud: "Getting different cardinalities in different cases doesn't mean anything": I think you're avoiding what the OP is asking. it does mean *something*: it means the formal expression $\left\{a,b\right\}$ does not denote a unique object, because it could denote a set with one element or a set with two elements. the question is really about the symbolic expressions we use to denote sets; the OP is conflating name with referent. you're right that it's wrong to say the cardinality isn't uniquely determined; what isn't uniquely determined is the referent of $\left\{a,b\right\}$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Of course it denotes a unique object, otherwise you can't meaningfully write it. But I do agree with you, the OP seems to be looking at $\{a,b\}$ as a formal expression, but this isn't in the language of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: If your reasoning, why the cardinality of $\{a,b\}$ is uniquely defined, is correct, then also my reasoning, why a real number $x$ with $x^2=1$ is unique, should be correct. Because the later statement is wrong, there must be a better explanation why the cardinality of $\{a,b\}$ is uniquely defined... Do you see my point? In both argumentations we made a case differentiation with unique conclusions in the end.

Comment: @GitGud: okay, there may be some confusion in what the OP and I have meant by "not uniquely determined." what the OP means is that we don't know, a priori, which set the expression $\left\{a,b\right\}$ stands for: in that sense its referent isn't determined. but I agree with you, of course, that "the cardinality of" is a function of sets, not of formal expressions. I think what's at issue here is whether we treat the letters as constants or as variables: think of the analogy between open sentences and closed sentences, where the former doesn't have a truth value until you assign values.

Comment: @symplectomorphic: "what isn't uniquely determined is the referent of $\{a,b\}$"... Thanks for this clearer formulation! ;-)

Comment: @tampis: Your reasoning with $x^2=1$ is formally entirely different from Mauro's statement. The arithmetic analogy to your original question is whether $x^2$ gives you a unique number, because it seems like it might not because there are negative *and* positive numbers that give you the same square. Mauro's answer is that all that being a well-defined function involves is taking the negative number to exactly one square, and the positive to exactly one square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is true that the uniqueness of the set, meaning its well-definability, does not imply that its cardinality is unique.

To phrase that in a clearer and more accurate way, proving that a set is well-defined does not mean that we can prove its cardinality is anything in particular.

Consider the set defined as follows $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid (x=x\land\mathrm{RH})\lor(x\neq x\land\lnot\mathrm{RH})\}$. If $\mathrm{RH}$ is true, then this set is $\Bbb N$, if it is false then the set is empty.

We can prove that this set is well-defined, because we can write this expressed in the language of set theory (albeit in a complicated way), and the axiom schema of separation tells us that this is a well-defined set. Can you prove if it's empty or not? Maybe, if you can prove the Riemann Hypothesis. (Okay, so $\rm RH$ might end up provable, if you want a real doozie, replace it in the definition by something provably unprovable like the Continuum Hypothesis, or something like that.)

The first answer is correct. Extensionality proves that either this set is a pair, or it is a singleton, but it is well-defined nonetheless.

Comment: Funny answer. Looks like $(x=x\land\mathrm{RH})\lor(x\neq x\land\lnot\mathrm{RH} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{RH}$ no matter the value of $x$. Any particular reason it wouldn't be OK to just write $\{x \in \mathbb{N} : \mathrm{RH} \}$?

Comment: Mike, yes, it would be the same thing. I just wanted to make it explicit.

Comment: @Asaf, I need some more explanations, please. If the above set is well-defined, it is so from a "platonist" point of view (I mean, a not-constructive one). Thus, if the above set is "real" it has a unique cardinality, also if we do not know which (and perhaps we will never know). We are unable to prove which is its cardinality, but in what sense we conclude that it is not unique ?

Comment: @Mauro: (1) Surely *you* don't need more explanation; (2) I need more explanation about your comment. If you are a Platonist and you agree that the universe of sets satisfies $\sf ZFC$, what is the cardinality of $X=\begin{cases}\varnothing &\sf CH\\\{\varnothing\}&\lnot\sf CH\end{cases}$, and certainly this set is well-defined (since we agreed that the universe of sets satisfies $\sf ZFC$ and this set is defined using separation).

Comment: @Asaf - I'm "unsatisfied" with "not unique". I do not know which is, but in what sense is not unique ? Can it be both ? like Schrodinger's cat ? CH is *undecided*, right ? so the card of set $X$ is "undefined" ? we cannot prove that is $=0$ or $=1$, so it is "uncomputable" ? I think that my mistake is to "think at" *cardinality* as a "property" of the set...

Comment: @Mauro: Yes, but if you are a platonist (even for the sake of argument), then surely you must believe that $\sf CH$ is either true or false; meaning the set I defined in my previous comment has a particular value which is either this or the other, but certainly not both. I think that your mistake was to assume the Platonist role here, when the theory is so very incomplete. ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks; I've to read again the relavant chapter of your textbook on the *Foundations of S-T* ... :)

Comment: @Mauro: You will need to use forcing argument to have me write it; so in a sense everything that can be written will be written there. But on the other hand, it's going to be a very generic book! ;-)

Comment: I guess that it is "typical" *set-theoretic* irony ...

Comment: @Mauro: It's definitely untyped. (In more than one way!)

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you answered your own question when you said the answer depends on whether $a$ and $b$ are fixed, known quantities, or whether they are parameters which you can dial according to your whim. I would say discussing the cardinality of 
$$X_{a,b} := \{a,b\}$$ 
is a lot like discussing the cardinality of 
$$Y_r := \{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : 1 \leq x < r\}.$$
The set, and the cardinality, depends on the values of the parameters.
\begin{align*}
X_{1,2} = \{1,2\} && X_{1,\varnothing} = \{1,\varnothing\} && X_{4,4} = \{4,4\} = \{4\} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
Y_5  = \{1,2,3,4\} && Y_{3.8} = \{1,2,3\} && Y_{-2} = \varnothing
\end{align*}
You could even make a case that
\begin{align*}
Y_{+\infty} = \{1,2,3,4,\ldots\} && Y_{\varnothing} = \varnothing
\end{align*}
since comparing an integer with a $+\infty$ is sometimes allowed, but it never makes sense to compare and integer to $\varnothing$. Maybe showing someone this second example where it seems more obvious that the set can have multiple cardinalities could clarify something about the first example.